# Multi select dropdown with checkbox & search method

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, checkbox

is there any plugin that can do this?

I have a Spring MVC project, so it needs to be in html/JavaScript/java something..

Something like this: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ , the second one (Multiple Select), but it doesn't have checkboxes. Also a good thing would be to have select all option on top of it, but that's optional.
So in short:
-Search
-Multi checkbox for multiple choices

Thanks in forehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really related to Spring directly. It's more of a HTML/JS (front-end) issue. If you like the way that the select box works on the link you provided, and it fits the scope of your project, then there's a few steps you'd want to take:

1. Render the select box as normal with whichever HTML templating framework you are using with Spring (whether Themeleaf, JSP, Handlebars, or something else). Make sure there is a `multiple` attribute in the `select` tag.
2. Download and add the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library to this page (required for the "plugin" in the link).
3. Download and add the Chosen file from your link to your page *after* jQuery.
4. Activate the plugin as [described](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#setup).

Here's a brief skeleton of how I would do it (as rendered HTML, not the template; which depends on implementation):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="chosen-select" multiple>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/resources/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would definitely recommend reading into jQuery and JavaScript in general on top of all of this. I hope this helps get you rolling!

Comment: Btw, what is that multi tag at the end? on line 5

Comment: @benskiiii I should have spelled that `multiple`, not `multi`. I've adjusted the answer accordingly. Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) about that attribute in the `select` element.

Comment: Whilst this answer is very helpful in terms of showing one how to install the plugin. It doesn't answer the OP's question regarding an alternative which uses check boxes.